# Flask: Create downloadable link for Excel file created with Openpyxl

Tags: flask, download, azure-blob-storage, openpyxl

I am creating a dynamic excel file based on user input using openpyxl. I want to embed this file as a downloadable link for the user to access on a separate webpage.

I have been able to save the file in my application's folder structure, but I am unsure how to access it from there. Since the file is dynamically created for each potential user, it cannot be stored in the static folder. Thus, I am unsure how to pass the excel sheet as a downloadable object to the user.

I attempted uploading the file to azure blob storage, and accessing it there as well, but I was hit with a permission denied error. I used this code snippet to attempt to access it:

block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path('dynamicfile',blob.name,blob.name)

Any advice on how to solve this problem, whether with or without azure blob, would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to adjust parts to your needs, but at least you get the idea.

```
from flask import send_file
from os.path import join

if request.form['action'] == 'Download':
    return send_file(os.path.join(app.config['DOWNLOAD_DIR'],'filename'),as_attachment=True)
```

Don't forget to set the download folder in your app config and a button with the correct value in your template.